# Elasticsearch how synonym token filter works if synonym is multi-word?

Tags: elasticsearch, filter, synonym

Can somebody explain me please how synonym token filter works if synonym is multi-word expression and tokenizer is whitespace? E.g. if I have this simple mapping

```
PUT /test_index
{
    "settings": {
        "index" : {
            "analysis" : {
                "analyzer" : {
                    "synonym" : {
                        "tokenizer" : "whitespace",
                        "filter" : ["synonym"]
                    }
                },
                "filter" : {
                    "synonym_graph" : {
                        "type" : "synonym",
                        "lenient": true,
                        "synonyms" : ["multi word, bar => baz"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I dont understand how is possible to evaluate term **multi word** if **whitespace tokenizer** breaks it in to **two words** multi and word. So as I understand it synonym filter never gets "**multi word**" as one term to find synonyms in configuration. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Your example throws an error

Comment: Moreover what version of elasticsearch are you using?

Comment: Yes there is a wrong filter name. Version is 6.8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer can be found in this section

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/7.6/token-graphs.html

and this blog post

http://blog.mikemccandless.com/2012/04/lucenes-tokenstreams-are-actually.html

> Some token filters can add tokens that span multiple positions. These can include tokens for multi-word synonyms, such as using "atm" as a synonym for "automatic teller machine". However, only some token filters, known as graph token filters, accurately record the positionLength for multi-position tokens.
>
> Indexing ignores the positionLength attribute and does not support token graphs containing multi-position tokens. However, queries, such as the match or match_phrase query, can use these graphs to generate multiple sub-queries from a single query string.

```
The following token filters can add tokens that span multiple positions but only record a default positionLength of 1:

- synonym
- word_delimiter

This means these filters will produce invalid token graphs for streams containing such tokens.

Avoid using invalid token graphs for search. Invalid graphs can cause unexpected search results.
```

Comment: So am I right if I think synonym filter is not for multi-word terms and instead I should use synonym_graph fitler? I am still not sure about it.

Comment: there is no synonym graph token filter in 6.8 , at least it is not mentioned in the docs.

Comment: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.8/analysis-synonym-graph-tokenfilter.html

Comment: My bad. As I see it although not exactly sure, you should use a synonym filter when indexing and a synonym graph when searching (index analyzer, search analyzer)

Comment: I am facing similar kinds of issues, so I tried to use synonym type as the index analyzer, and synonym_graph as the search_analyzer. Still, results are not as expected